# div + scroll + fixed bottom + variable top

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with sizing a scrolling div to fill the window, considering that I have one or more top divs and a footer div.

```
this is what I need

+------------------+    +------------------+    +------------------+
|      top1        |    |      top1        |    |      top1        |
+------------------+    +------------------+    +------------------+
|      top2        |    |      top2        |    |                |^|
|                  |    +------------------+    |                | |
+------------------+    |                |^|    |                | |
|                |^|    |                | |    |      scroll    | |
|                | | => |      scroll    | | => |                | |
|      scroll    | |    |                | |    |                | |
|                | |    |                | |    |                | |
|                | |    |                | |    |                | |
|                |v|    |                |v|    |                |v|
+------------------+    +------------------+    +------------------+
|      footer      |    |      footer      |    |      footer      |
+------------------+    +------------------+    +------------------+
```

**Top1** has a fixed height.

**Footer** has a fixed height.

**Top2** doesn't have a fixed height and sometimes doesn't even appear.

The only way I know to do that is by defining the container height, fixing its top and its bottom. But I cannot fix the top property since the top2 div has variable height...

Can someone help me?

html:

```
<body>
    <div id='top1'>Top1</div>
    <div id='top2'>Top2</div>
    <div id='container'>
       <ul id='data'>
          <li>item1</li>
          <li>item2</li>
          <li>item3</li>
          <li>item4</li>
          <li>item5</li>
          <li>item6</li>
          <li>item7</li>
          <li>item8</li>
          <li>item9</li>
          <li>item10</li>
       </ul> 
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#top1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#top2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #BBB;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

#data li {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is javascript an option? If so, you can calculate the top(s) and the footer heights, add them, and then substract them from the window height. The result is the remaining height to apply to 'scroll'.

Comment: Maybe this fiddle is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/NvbYH/

Comment: It would be better if it could be implemented without JS, but I'm affraid it can't be done.

Comment: You need to add height for overflow to work. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/rWnD2/. what else is needed?

Comment: I did using javascript... thanks anyway

Comment: It would be great if CSS would allow a static top and a fixed/absolute bottom. Maybe in a next version of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

1. first get windows height by this function
   $( window ).height();
2. and make one more function for top2
   $( document ).height();
3. pluse heights 1st header + 2nd footer +.3rd top2 ( get by this function $( document ).height();)
4. minus height in windows height
5. then will get new height and apply on scrlloing div
6. one more thing for make better scrlloing  use resizing function