# CSS variable top fixed bottom has foxed me

Tags: html, css

Thanks for taking a look, I'm making a webapp that has a menu feature where there is an overlay with a title, description, options for adding a new component (think a form with a number of input fields) and a save or cancel button at the bottom. The Title has no linebreaks and always has a constant height, same for the button bar, these go at the top and bottomn (blue and pink in the example), the description can have a varying number of lines and as such the height is variable (green area). The input options can also have a varying number of lines but can only be placed in the remaining container area. So what I have is this:

[image]

And what I would like to have is this:

[image]

Where the height of the green field is variable, and the yellow field fills the remaining space with a fixed title and buttons at the bottom. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htm1wto4/) (code pasted after the question) with a JS function that generates 1 - 5 lines of description (green field) to simulate the varying height.

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution and have spent a few days researching this . I've tried various combinations of CSS position, float and display commands, flex boxes, table layouts etc but unfortunately can't put my finger on the solution. I'm aware as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441251/div-scroll-fixed-bottom-variable-top) that a javascript approach is possible but if I go this way i'd consider it over complex, likely to confuse future coders working on the tool and I'd like to improve my knowledge.

Thanks in advance,

James

```js
var EHeader = document.getElementById("desc");
var DescLine = "desc<br/>";
var DescLines = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

EHeader.innerHTML = DescLine.repeat(DescLines);
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#title {
  background-color: blue;
}
#desc {
  background-color: green;
}
#options {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">title</div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
  <div id="input">
    <div id="options">option 0
      <br/>option 1
      <br/>option 2
      <br/>option 3
      <br/>option 4
      <br/>option 5
      <br/>option 6
      <br/>option 7
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="button">button bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to to is:

1. Set `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column` on `container` element.
2. Set `overflow-y: auto` and `flex: 1` on `flop` element.

Also if you want `options` or (yellow div) to always take rest of free space even if there are small number of options you can do [`THIS`](https://jsfiddle.net/htm1wto4/2/)

```js
var EHeader = document.getElementById("desc");
var DescLine = "desc<br/>";
var DescLines = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

EHeader.innerHTML = DescLine.repeat(DescLines);
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#flop {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
#title {
  background-color: blue;
}
#desc {
  background-color: green;
}
#options {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#button {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">title</div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
  <div id="flop">
    <div id="options">option 0
      <br/>option 1
      <br/>option 2
      <br/>option 3
      <br/>option 4
      <br/>option 5
      <br/>option 6
      <br/>option 7
      <br/>option 8
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="button">button bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know flex could be used like that.

Comment: Nenad - thanks for your help here, apologies for the delay replying, this was a fight to implement. Will add an answer (accepted yours) with some pointers for those that follow.

Answer (score 1):

For your current html, if you intend to use `br` to separate the options then I can suggest setting the height of `#options` to value equal to line-height of the text times the number of lines you want to display i.e. `lineHeight *  totalLines`

for the filling snippet, i assumed line height as 20px. So for 4 items, the height is 20 * 4 = 80px.

```js
var EHeader = document.getElementById("desc");
var DescLine = "desc<br/>";
var DescLines = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

EHeader.innerHTML = DescLine.repeat(DescLines);
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#title {
  background-color: blue;
}
#desc {
  background-color: green;
}
#options {
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">title</div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
  <div id="input">
    <div id="options">option 0
      <br/>option 1
      <br/>option 2
      <br/>option 3
      <br/>option 4
      <br/>option 5
      <br/>option 6
      <br/>option 7
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="button">button bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hopper - thanks for the effort here, in the end I went with Nenads approach

Comment: Yeah, that's better than mine. I learned from your question too... cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just adding further feedback here for anybody trying to implement this in Chrome, as made clear [here](https://nostrongbeliefs.com/flexbox-vertical-ordering/):

> This is fine in all browsers except Chrome, which goes completely buck mad with disappearing content, overlapping content and huge spaces (screenshot). Somehow the floats in one box throw grenades all over the rest of the page.

In the end to get Chrome to play nicely it was necessary to remove all `float: left` CSS markup from child tags. The code example given in the question was a minimal example, in reality the child elements inside the flex box are more complex. Usings Nenads pointers I was able to get the bottom of the description and the top of the menu section to meet up with the proper expansion but had to use dummy margins on the child elements inside the scrollable area (With the `first-child` and `last-child` css markers to create the space for the borders on the description (above) and button bar (below).

Regards,

James